# Did any computer actually use the KR580VM1?

Tags: cpu, ussr

The KR580VM1 (or КР580ВМ1) is a CPU from Soviet Ukraine that is not directly equivalent to any Western ones. It's basically an Intel 8080 with another register pair, H1L1, and another address space which can contain data but not executable code. Instruction prefixes control the use of H1L1 and the second address space.

Sounds like a great product, right?

The thing is I cannot find any evidence that this chip was ever used anywhere by anyone. Maybe the Z80 clones plus bank switching mechanisms eclipsed the KR580VM1's usefulness. Maybe it was used only in embedded applications that nobody writes about today. So my question is if this CPU actually was used in any products

Comment: If it were used in items for the Soviet military, finding information about that might be difficult.

Comment: @RichF Good point. I think the Soviet military mostly use domestic CPUs (mostly BESM6/Elbrus type stuff), I guess the 'VM1 could fit in that category

Comment: Some [Вектор-06Ц](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-06C) are known to be fitted with a КР580ВМ1 - which is easy as it is in Mode 0 mostly compatible with the default  КР580ВМ80А. The [Virtual Vector](http://sensi.org/scalar/ware/552/) emulator does support the КР580ВМ1 extensions. --- And no, I do not own any of them :( --- BTW, the КР580ВМ1 was not made in (Sowjet) Russia, but Ukraine, by "Квазар" (Quasar) in Kiew.

Comment: @Raffzahn it seems like a start to a good answer.

Comment: Not sure as it doesn't show any that has been made do from the start. While proving otherwise is impossible. I'll copy it into an answerand lets see that else comes up.

Comment: To compliment Raffzahn's answer: it's unlikely that this chip was ever factory-installed into any home PCs produced in late 80s-early 90s. Still, DIY enthusiasts did consider it as a viable upgrade for certain Soviet home computers, including Vector and Lviv. The problem was, though, that the new chip was not 100% backwards compatible, as certain command codes undocumented (but used by some software) in the original BM80 were used for completely different operations in BM1

Comment: @DmytroL Oh that's interesting, and the BM80's undocumented opcodes the same as the western analogue?

Comment: @OmarL at least part of them were the same:
08h, 10h, 18h, 20h, 28h, 30h, 38h - NOP
0CBh - JMP
0D9h - RET
0DDh, 0EDh, 0FDh - CALL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Sounds like a great product, right?

It does. 64 KiB code + 64 KiB data is about the ideal structure for an 8 bit CPU with 16 bit addressing.

> The thing is I cannot find any evidence that this chip was ever used anywhere by anyone.

It came not only late, but as well at a rather troubled time, followed by an extreme fast swing to simply buying world standard CPUs.

> Maybe it was used only in embedded applications that nobody writes about today. So my question is if this CPU actually was used in any products

None that I know of. But there are reports of [Вектор-06Ц](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-06C) (Vector-06Z) to be fitted with a КР580ВМ1 - which is easy as it is in Mode 0 mostly compatible with the default КР580ВМ80А.

The [Virtual Vector](http://sensi.org/scalar/ware/552/) emulator does support the КР580ВМ1 extensions.

Comment: "It came not only late", do you know when?

Comment: @OmarL Not exactly, must have been 1988..90. much like a stop gap before going to 16 bit.

Comment: Also, Mode 0? Implies there are other modes, not compatible with the вм80. I have found anything about that. Are you able to elaborate?

Comment: @OmarL Not really. It's a bit like with the 8086 min and max mode. like there mode select is done by pulling a pin. The VM1 is in Mode 0 (mostly) like an 8080 pinout - except not needing -5 and +12 Volt and Phi2. -5 is turned into  the mode select and PHI2 now carries a M/IO, while Mode  1 is closer to an 8085 in offering an INT/INTA interrupt mechanic. and ready instead of wait. and ofc A16 to select the memory spaces.